# Call a javascript function after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below test code to call a javascript function from ajax method after the success block and pass the success value to a javascript funtion.It's working fine. Now i want to get javascript return message from ajax call. It always return null.

```
    $.ajax({
      url:"getvalue.php",  
      success:function(data) {
         var retval= change_format(data); 
         alert(retvl);//always return null
         I can't get the result
      }
   });


function change_format(data)
{
 do something.....
 value = "Some Data"; having some data
 return value;
}
```

Comment: whether `change_format` uses another ajax function?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with `change_format()`, not `testAjax()`. We can't help you if you don't show what it does.

Comment: I find it nothing wrong.. how will ajax work if `testAjax()` is not called. Can you put more details?

Comment: Please see my code  again..

Comment: `var retval= change_format(data); ` vs `alert(retvl);` different variables name `retval`and `retvl`.

Comment: Many be you need to make it async

Answer (score -1):

Add a callback to your `testAjax` function

```
 function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      url:"getvalue.php",  
      success:function(data) {
         var retval= change_format(data); 
         alert(retvl);//always return null
         arguments[0](retvl);
        // I can't get the result
      }
    });
}




function change_format(a) {
    // do everything here
}

testAjax(change_format);
```

Comment: where  i add the callback

Comment: add the callback function without `()` as an argument to your calling function

Answer (score -3):

The $.ajax sucks. Why not just use the load(). Simple but very powerful.
Deploy the algorithm in the code below:

```
    <div id="stage">RESULT SHOWS HERE</div>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
$("#stage").load("URL?PARAMETERS");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.load()` and `.ajax()` have completely different purposes. Your example assumes that the response should be rendered on the page exactly as its received, whereas OP's example shows that he's trying to use the result in a separate function. And why does `$.ajax` *"suck"*? Consider providing some sort of basis for your claim, otherwise it means nothing.

Comment: Not to mention you're answering a question from 2013. Now I don't think that's inherently bad, sometimes new information presents itself and it's good to keep older questions up-to-date. However, for the reasons I mentioned above, I don't believe that's the case here.

Comment: `.load()` is just a shorthand for `.ajax` with the appropriate options.