# How to run a JavaScript function after a successful jQuery Ajax request to ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a simple website that has a login/sign up feature.
I just want to let the user get a message after he successfully sign in or  sign up.

Here's my login method

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username,string password)
    {
        User loginTest = DB.Users.Where(a => a.User_Name.Equals(username) && a.User_Password.Equals(password)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (loginTest != null)
        {


            //some code
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'm calling the login method like this

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "logged-in", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
                        {
                         <input type="text" />
                         <input type="password" />
                         <input type="submit" value="login">
                         }
```

Here's my javascript function that I want to run if the logging in is successful.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function JSalert(){
swal("Logged in successfully");
     }
  </script>
```

I already added

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

And I tested the function on button click and it's working, I'm just new to this and I wonder how to call this function after the user log in.

I checked these links already but I couldn't get any help.

[Call a javascript function after ajax success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884579/call-a-javascript-function-after-ajax-success)

[Run javascript function after Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223837/run-javascript-function-after-postback)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `Login` via AJAX?

Comment: so learn about ajax

Comment: Where is your AJAX request code?

Comment: You're returning an ActionResult from your actionMethod when the user logs in, which you've not mentioned here, perhaps you can mention that or use AJAX requests to log in and dynamically change the content using JS

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: perhaps you didn't understand my comment, I'm asking what do you return from the actionMethod which in your case is `public ActionResult Login(string username,string password)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You don't have to use that *Ajax.BeginForm*. You can write some pure HTML.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="login">
    <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="button" value="Log In" id="postIt">
</form>
```

In order to make Ajax call, add some JavaScript/jQuery code into the same cshtml file.

```
<script>
$("#postIt").click(function() {
    postIt();
});
function postIt() {
    var usr = $("#username").val();
    var pwd = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Login/LogMeIn",
        data: { "Username": usr, "Password": pwd },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.result) {// logged in
                JSalert(data.result);
            } else {// unauthorized
                JSalert(data.result);
            }
        }
    });
}
function JSalert(msgType) {
    if (msgType) {
        swal("Logged in successfully", "Welcome to StackOverflow", "success");
    } else {
        swal("You're not authorized", "Welcome to StackOverflow", "error");  
    }
}
</script>
```

Then, add a simple login method into the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LogMeIn(LoginModel data)
{
    if (data.Username == "rightUser" && data.Password == "rightPass")
    {
        return Json(new { result = true, message = "welcome" });
    }
    return Json(new { result = false, message = "unauthorized" });
}
```

**LoginModel.cs**

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very understandable, but i guess in this way it will show me and simple alert message, what if I want to show my function which is JSalert()

Comment: I've edited the answer. It includes the alert function and more information about project structure now.

Comment: one last thing, what do you mean by LoginModel data, because in my project I have a big viewModel that contains loads of data(tables,lists...), so is there any way to pass the username and the password like I did before :(string username, string password) ,thanks in advance

Comment: I've edited the answer again, you can see and clone that LoginModel. Also, don't forget the take a look at secure authentication mechanisms when you get this concept.

Comment: I created a new LoginModel like you did, but the data passed into LogMeIn is always null

Comment: Is there any other form in the same page? What is the type of your button? And, make sure that there is no typo in your HTML code.

Comment: No, but there are many contents in the page that are loading from the viewmodel

Comment: It's difficult to comment without further details. Just try it with a new controller and view in order to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to show alert or any message after the redirection.

1. You can set some flag in query string while redirecting the user. In your java-script code, check if the flag exists, show user the message.
2. Set a java-script variable in while rendering the view and check that variable to show message or not.
3. You can also use local-storage or create a cookie, but that is never preferred.

In your redirect statement use the below code

```
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()+"login_success=1");
```

In your ajax success, use the below code, it will work

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("login_success=1")){
//call your function
}
```

Comment: I'm super new to this, can you show me how to do that?

Comment: are you using an ajax call on form submit?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Ajax.BeginForm

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
   using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post",  OnSuccess = "onSuccess" })){
       //your code
    }
```

In your js:

```
function onSuccess(result) {
   //return your message here
}
```

Comment: I did this but the js function is not being called

Comment: Is there any error in console? Make sure you have tagged your actionmethod with **`[HttpPost]`**

Comment: I added  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
and now it's working, but it's showing me the alert message even when the username and password are incorrect

Comment: You can return flag from controller whether it is success or not and you will get it in **result** parameter of JS function

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method

```
@using (
Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions(){
HttpMethod = "POST",OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" 
}, new { 
@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" 
}))
{
}
```

JS Function:

```
 function OnSuccess(response) {
        if (response.status === 'validationerror') {
           //your code
        } else {
           //your code
        }
    }
```